# AdMob eCPM and earnings drastically reducing ever since the GDPR warning appeared on AdMob console

Tags: android, ios, admob, gdprconsentform

My AdMob eCPM has drastically reduced by half ever since the GDPR warning appeared on the AdMob console. I have added all necessary consent in all of my apps, both Android and iOS, but the error still remains and my eCPM continues to drop.

I also don't know if this is related, but for some strange reason, I have been having a high rate of apps that are not mine showing in the "**Apps to Confirm**" tab in the AdMob console. I have of course blocked ads from showing on these apps from the console.

The weird thing is that these apps are from more than 20 different developers, and when I checked the update section of the Play Store for these apps, some of them have not been updated for more than 3 years. So how can they be using my publisher ID if they haven't been updated that long?

I'm not sure what's causing these issues, but I'm hoping someone here can help me figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find out what was the issue? Having similar issue now

Answer (score 0):

**Apps to Confirm ->** Let assume you are testing your app and you change package name to some random app pakage name (xyz) but that package name belongs to some one else and also live on play store in that case admob thinks that you are owner of that (xyz)  package name they send you app confirm so you confirm that your ids are not using unintentionally
Same happen if some one else put your ads and either test or try to target you and spamming you by changing already publish apps

**Solution is to implement way to secure the ads ids**

**have not been updated for more than 3 years.?**
For testing just create empty project and add **ADS** integration and change package name to any app on play store like **com.google.android.youtube**  after some days admob send you
this **Apps to Confirm"**  option.
As Far as GDPR is Concered
https://github.com/Moeenuddin178/UmpGoogleAdmobGDPRr
I have created the implementation for this

Either wait for some time So GDPR library come to stable And for time being just don't implement the GDPR

Comment: Please explain more on this.

Comment: lets assume I have your ads ids in my app and I change it package name to already publish app and start using app admob thinks that I have attached the ads in other app on play store so basically your ads ids need to be secure

Comment: okay , how do you propose i secure my ads id? ads id are always open to being reversed engineered . so what should i do?

Comment: Load ids or api keys from gradle  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59792952/do-i-need-to-keep-admob-ad-unit-ids-in-a-safe-place